Модель OSI. TCP, SSL хэндшейк
Согласно модели сначала идет Прикладной уровень за ним уровень представления и транспортный. Но почему, например, когда браузер сформировал https запрос, TCP рукопожатие происходит раньше, чем TLS рукопожатие?
Расскажите, пожалуйста, "чайнику".

А что не сходится? Запрос на соединение идет сверху вниз по уровням, а само соединение устанавливается снизу вверх. Не может быть TLS рукопожатия пока TCP не готово.

TLS - это более высокоуровневая штука, TCP - это нижний уровень. Верхний уровень работает через нижний.

в данном случае, TCP для TLS является "транспортом".

То есть во время запроса на соединение (сверху вниз) данные просто шифруются (TLS) и формируются сегменты (TCP), а снизу вверх уже соответственно устанавливается TCP соединение и расшифровываются данные (TLS). Верно?

Что-то каша какая-то, сперва браузер и сервер устанавливают друг с другом TCP-соединение, а потом внутри этого соединения начинают передавать TLS-данные, никаких "сверху вниз" и "снизу вверх" придумывать не надо

Тогда для чего существуют понятия инкапсуляция и декапсуляция? Объясните, пожалуйста, я вообще ботинок. Я реально не понимаю почему уровень, где используется TLS выше а tcp раньше))

Потому что вы не можете просто так взять и передать TLS-данные, вам нужен транспорт который займётся этой передачей, вот в качестве такого транспорта и выступает TCP

я понял, что tcp раньше, я не понимаю в контексте модели OSI. Согласно этой модели TLS соединение устанавливается раньше

Непонятно с чего вы это взяли, в той же википедии в статье про OSI шифрование нарисовано в уровне представления, то есть после TCP который на транспортном уровне

И вообще всё относительно. Вот из Википедии: "Определения протокола прикладного уровня и уровня представления очень размыты, и принадлежность протокола к тому или иному уровню, например, протокола HTTPS, зависит от конечного сервиса который предоставляет приложение." Ну и т.д.

Ну и в целом лично для меня одного лишь факта, что канальный и сетевой уровни могут работать поверх прикладного (любой VPN), уже достаточно, чтобы отправить модель OSI на свалку истории. Ну и всякие приколы про какие-нибудь ICMP-туннели, когда сетевой уровень внезапно становится прикладным, дополнительно намекают, что не надо воспринимать модель OSI слишком всерьёз

Спасибо всем. Я в начале думал что хэндшейки как раз во время инкапсуляции и деинкапсуляции идут. Теперь понятно, что инкапсуляция данных происходит после установления соединений, обеспечивая правильную упаковку и передачу данных через сеть.

@Михаил При этом один и тот же протокол может в принципе встречаться сразу на нескольких уровнях несколько раз.

А вот кстати с «после установления соединений» связан ещё один прикол 0-RTT, когда браузер, заранее зная параметры сервера, может прям сразу отправить зашифрованные данные — то есть всего за одну отправку пакета одновременно и установить соединение, и наладить шифрование, и сразу же отправить зашифрованный HTTP-запрос. Ещё один гвоздь в крышку гроба OSI

Тогда же зачем они во все книжки этот OSI пихают???? Собирался сегодня вообще прочитать "Kubernetes и сети" OREILLY Джейм Стронг, Валлери Лэнси. Там все начинается как раз с этой OSI. Начал читать, появились вопросы. В итоге целый день разбирался с OSI, а не кубером)

Ну потому что это классика. Я тоже никогда не понимал, нафига этот OSI. Он сферический в вакууме, лучше конкретные протоколы вроде TCP, UDP, HTTP и прочего такого выучить и их взаимоотношение.

Справедливости ради, в книжке так и написано «протоколы OSI не получили широкого использования», а дальше предлагается более простая «модель TCP/IP», которая несколько ближе к реальности (хотя всё равно довольно условная)
